# Error in making new project in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, compilation

I've installed android developing tools; JRE,JDK and also sdk are installed correctly. (I think they're correctly installed!)
now, I want to make new android project with eclipse, but in that wizard, "Complie with" field is empty. because of that the "Next" button is unavailable.
so I can't make new project.
what should I do?

http://s1.picofile.com/file/7525051391/error.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already downloaded and installed Android SDK you should :

1) Open Eclipse
2) Go to Window > Preferences > Android
3) Check the SDK location

If everything is configured well than you should see few Android platform available, check for API 7.
If it's not there use Android SDK manager to download it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you installed a SDK Platform for one of the Android API?
Open the Android SDK Manager and download the SDK Platforms you need.

Comment: How?
would you mind explaining in details, please?